# How to get an array from an array in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, mongodb, meteor

everyone. I would like the students who enroll a subject are shown in a table when this subject is selected in a dropdown list. The ID of these students is stored in an array. The problem is that this ID array retrieved from the document looks kind of strange. seem like there is an array in an array.
Like this shown in the console: 
     [shown in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBHXF.png)

```
 {enrollment: Array(2)}
     enrollment: Array(2)
     0: "b1602231"   
     1: "B1560124"   
     length: 2 
     __proto__: Array(0)
     __proto__: Object
```

And it throwed an error: Exception in template helper: Error: $in needs an array

So how could I solve this? I would really appreciate it if someone can give me some idea.

Below is the event handler and helper.

```
Template.subject.events({
  ‘change #dropdown’: function(event, template) {
    var selectedValue = $(event.target).val();
    var array = subject.findOne( { subjectCode:selectedValue }, { fields:{ _id:0, enrollment:1 } } );
    Session.set(‘studentEnrolled’,array);
  }
});

Template.student.helpers({
  student: function() {
    var listOfStudent = Session.get( ‘studentEnrolled’ );
    return student.find( { studentID: { $in:listOfStudent } } );
  }
});
```

//HTML

```
<template name="student">
        {{#each student}}
        <tr>
          <td>{{name}}</td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
</template>
```

Comment: Are you sure there's an array within an array? From what I can see it looks like there is just a single array in the console output.

Comment: @Leafyshark I am not sure about that. Because that ```__proto__``` attribute confuses me.

Comment: please can you edit your post with a screenshot of the console.log instead of copy/paste?

Comment: @Leafyshark Sure, I just uploaded it

Comment: Okay, it's just a single array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying my answer from the forums:

First of all, you are taking the whole subject document (and after the first answer, wrapping that array into another array) here:

```
Session.set('studentEnrolled',[array]);
```

Which means when you search here:

```
return student.find({studentID:{$in:listOfStudent}});
```

You are passing an array with a document in it, instead of the enrollments array.

What you want to do is store the enrollments in the session:

```
Session.set('studentEnrolled', array.enrollments);
```

I'd also recommend renaming the variable `array` since it's not an array, and that probably contributed to your confusion

Answer (score 1):

Find get `one records` from data. u can convert in array using `[data]`

```
var array = subject.findOne({subjectCode:selectedValue}, {fields:{_id:0, enrollment:1}});
Session.set(‘studentEnrolled’,[array]);
}
```

// For async update
More: https://blog.meteor.com/using-promises-and-async-await-in-meteor-8f6f4a04f998

```
Template.hello.onCreated(function helloOnCreated() {
  this.list = new ReactiveVar([]);
  Meteor.call('getHobbits', (error, result) => {
    this.list.set(result);
  });
});

Template.hello.helpers({
  hobbits() {
    return Template.instance().list.get();
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks.That error is fixed. But students are not showing in the table. Any idea?

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out.

Comment: Ig helps. please upvoate :-D

Comment: I wish I could but I have to earn enough reputation to upvote :(  Sorry about that.